# How to remotely deploy a secure websocket service on Tomcat10 through Maven

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, tomcat8, tomcat9, tomcat10

I have burned myself trying to set up a secure WebSocket service using my remote Tomcat10 server but without any success. I keep on getting from Postman "Unexpected server response: 404" after hitting "wss://mydomain.org:4123/ws". I attach the most important settings in case someone could hopefully spot what I am doing wrong.

I would like to mention that I am deploying with Maven the project from 127.0.0.1 via a Tunnel.

**server.xml**

```
...
<Service name="Catalina">
<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
           port="5123"
           compression="off"
           protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           />

<Connector port="4123"
           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="100"
           compression="off"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           SSLEnabled="true"
           scheme="https"
           secure="true">

  <SSLHostConfig >
    <Certificate  certificateFile="path/to/certificateFile"
                  certificateKeyFile="path/to/certificateKeyFile"
                  certificateChainFile="path/to/certificateChainFile" />
  </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>

<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
...
  <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
...
  </Host>
</Engine>
```

**pom.xml**

```
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lambdaworks</groupId>
        <artifactId>scrypt</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>My_WebService</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://127.0.0.1:5123/manager/text</url>
                <path>/</path>
                <server>My-Server</server>
                <finalName>My_WebService</finalName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**web.xml**

```
...

<display-name>WS Engine</display-name>
<description>Desc.</description>

<resource-ref>
    <description>My Database</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/my-database</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>

<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.tomcat.websocket.binaryBufferSize</param-name>
    <param-value>65536</param-value>
</context-param>
```

**MainWsClass**

```
@ServerEndpoint("/ws")
public class MainWsClass {..}
```

Comment: 404 makes me feel that your app is not deployed or the url you're trying to access is not correct. Can you check that your war is deployed? if yes can you try this URL? wss://mydomain.org:4123/<war-name>/ws

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually ended up using the following POM which works:

```
...
<dependencies>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
  <artifactId>cargo-maven3-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.9</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.lambdaworks</groupId>
  <artifactId>scrypt</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
  <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
  <version>42.3.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
  <version>10.1.0-M10</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
  <version>10.1.0-M10</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
<finalName>My_WebService</finalName>
<plugins>

    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cargo-maven3-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.9</version>
    <configuration>
      <container>
        <containerId>tomcat10x</containerId>
        <type>remote</type>
      </container>
      <configuration>
        <type>runtime</type>
        <properties>
          <cargo.server.settings>My_WebService</cargo.server.settings>
        </properties>
      </configuration>
    </configuration>
    </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <webResources>
        <resource>
          <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
          <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
      </webResources>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

</plugins>
</build>
```